# Unable to save file inside Java project folders

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes

I have a Spring boot application which is deployed in Kubernetes pods. I am trying to write to a file within my project folders.

Project structure:

```
project
 - src
  - main
   - resources
  - test
```

I am trying to store a file under `src/main/resources/{folderName}/{fileName}`.

Code:

```
    File file = new File(filePath); // filePath is src/main/resources/{folderName}/{fileName}
    if (file.getParentFile() != null) {
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }
```

Once the path is created I'm using BufferedWriter to write my string into the file.
This works just fine locally. But it fails when deployed in Kubernetes pods.

Any suggestions on what can be done here?? Thanks!

Comment: "Any suggestions on" — a program really should not be writing into its own source directory tree. What is the actual _goal_ of writing the file there? (see https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Your source folders are in the execution environment?

Comment: Your java project most likely is compiled into a jar or war. What aled was alluding to is it's not typical for the source files to be deployed alongside the jar containing the compiled program.